# Droppable is not registering isOver when child component is not present

Tags: react-dnd

The logic of my chessboard is that I have a ChessBoard component made up of BoardSquare components. BoardSquare has an optional child component of ChessPiece. ChessPieces are draggable, and ChessSquares are droppable. When I try to move a piece to a square, the drop function is called and I'm able to retrieve the dropped square's coordinates. The issue is that when dragging over any empty square, isOver is not correctly being captured, and only applies the isOver classes when a piece is in the square.

[isOver](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uEDi7.jpg)

[No isOver](https://i.stack.imgur.com/owqdJ.jpg)

I've tried moving the useDrop ref to different layers without any success, and have explored using the connect argument with collect, but that throws some errors with the usage from the example.

Relevant components:

**Chessboard**

```
export default function ChessBoard() {
    const BOARD_SIZE = 8;
    const [view, setView] = useState(0) // 0 is white, 1 is black

    return (
        <DndProvider backend={HTML5Backend}>
            <div className={"flex h-screen"}>
                <div className={"m-auto"}>
                    {board.map((arr, y) => {
                        return (<div className="flex" key={y}>
                            {arr.map((arr, x) => {
                                return (
                                    <BoardSquare x={x} y={y} key={x + '-' + y} >
                                        {(x===0 || y===0) && (<ChessPiece key={x + '-' + y}/>)} // Test pieces
                                    </BoardSquare>
                                )}
                            )}
                        </div>)
                    })
                    }
                </div>
            </div>
        </DndProvider>
    )

}
```

**BoardSquare**

```
export default function BoardSquare(props: {x: number, y: number, children?: React.ReactNode}) {

    const move = (x :number,y : number) => {
        console.log(`Dropped at x: ${x}, y: ${y}`)
   }

    const [{ isOver, highlighted, hovered }, drop] = useDrop(() => ({
        accept: ItemTypes.PIECE,
        drop: () => move(props.x, props.y),
        collect: monitor => ({
            highlighted: monitor.canDrop(),
            hovered: monitor.isOver(),
            isOver: monitor.isOver(),
        }),
    }), [props.x, props.y])

    const classes = "box-border h-16 w-16 flex-none ";
    const color = (props.x + props.y) % 2 === 0 ? 'bg-gray-200' : 'bg-gray-600';
    const hoverClasses = 'z-10 opacity-50 bg-yellow-100'
    return (
        <div className={classes + color} ref={drop}>
            <div className={isOver ? hoverClasses : '' }>
                {props.children}
            </div>
        </div>
    )

}
```

**ChessPiece**

```
export default function ChessPiece() {

    const [{isDragging}, drag] =
        useDrag(
            () => (
                {
                    type: ItemTypes.PIECE,
                    collect: monitor => ({
                        isDragging: monitor.isDragging(),
                    }),
                }
            )
        )

    return (
        <div>
            <img
                ref={drag}
                style={{
                     opacity: isDragging ? .5 : 1,
                     cursor: 'move',
                     transform: `translate(0,0)`
                }}
                src={'pieces/b_bishop.png'}
            />
        </div>
    )

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This was a front-end oversite. I went down a rabbit hole of thinking this was some kind of child property error to do with react-dnd. Its not, the useDrop hook provides a ref to the dropTarget so this is already being watched. The highlight field which shows where you're about to drop a piece was set without a height or width, causing it not to render. Setting the inner div that renders hoverClasses (in tailwind using h-full w-full) solves the problem.